# Spring security domain ACL integration with EJB3

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security, ejb-3.0, acl, hibernate-4.x

I am building an application which has the services (EJB3 Stateless Session Beans & Hibernate4) layer  &  client web layer (Spring MVC) residing on different physical servers.

Client look up the service layer for all the services.All the data access is done at the service layer .

Spring security is used for authentication at the web application layer.

1) Is there a way to share the logged in user details with the service layer EJB application?
2) What would be the best option to authorize data acces? Is there some way to integrate the Spring security Domain object security ACL's with EJB3?

Appreciate your time & answers ..